# Cant seem to get past "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error

Tags: ios, swift

```
let root = "api.site.org" 

@IBAction func signupAccount(_ sender: Any) {
    let q = self.tempemail.text ?? "nil" 
    let w = self.tempusername.text ?? "nil" 
    let e = self.temppassone.text ?? "nil" 
    let r = self.temppasstwo.text ?? "nil"
    if q == "" || w == "" || e == "" {
        print("Please fill in all fields")
    } else {
        if e == r {
            let email = q
            let username = w
            let password = e
            let a = "username="+username
            let b = "&password="+password
            let c = "&email="+email
            let po = a+b+c
            let thingy = URL(string: root+"/signup");

            var request = URLRequest(url:thingy!)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.httpBody = po.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

                if error != nil
                {
                    print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        let Value = parseJSON["success"] as? Bool
                        if Value == true {
                            print("Signup Successful")
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } else {
            print("Passwords do not match.")
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the code I am currently using. For some reason on `line 42`, it triggers this `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101a8fb50)` and errors with `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

I'm not sure how to go about fixing this since `q,w,e,r` are all textfields.

For reference: `Line 42: let e = self.temppassone.text ?? "nil"`

Any help is very much appreciated. I've been pulling my hair out for quite a while. Not sure why it's "nil" if text is in the textfields when button is pressed. Very odd.

Comment: Is `temppassone` an `IBOutlet`? Is it correctly connected in the storyboard?

Comment: Indeed. I've already checked for this.

Comment: Why are you doing `let q = self.tempemail.text ?? "nil"` instead of `let q = self.tempemail.text ?? ""` What's the point of setting the string to `"nil"` instead of the empty string which you check for on the `if` statement?

Comment: If `let e = self.temppassone.text ?? "nil" ` is causing the crash then the outlet is *not* connected.

Comment: How are you creating this instance of the view controller?  A common cause of this issue is instantiating the view controller via an initialiser instead of through the storyboard resulting in the outlets being `nil`

Comment: I reconnected all of my outlets and that seem to have fixed it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that line of code could possibly fail with that error is if `temppassone` is nil. Put a breakpoint on the line and when execution stops type this in the console: `po self.temppassone`. I fully expect that the command will return `nil`. If it doesn't, then double check that the line of code referenced is really the one that is having the problem.

If `temppassone` is an IBOutlet and is returning nil, then try a clean and rebuild. (command-option-shift-K)

Comment: It does go "nil". How does one fix this issue?

Comment: Added more to the answer.

Comment: The same error came even after I cleaned and rebuilded it.